# :confirm and :method not working in rails button_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

i am having a problem with my rails 3 app

**In my view i have**

```
<%= button_to("Accept Post", {}, {:confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :accept_question, :remote => true}) %>
```

**The generated html is**

```
<form method="post" action="/questions/show/1" data-remote="true" class="button_to">
    <div>
        <input data-confirm="Are you sure?" type="submit" value="Accept Post" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Rv1CbqkE+61Fn4wb836eOENjyGkNpzzRrwMTywLZPf0=" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**my gem file is loading this**

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**The following .js files are appearing in the generated html**

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1309961714" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1309961714" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js?1305044364" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js?1309961714" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.tools.min.js?1309338309" type="text/javascript"> </scipt>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1309961714" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1309424326" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have seen other posts on this topic, but nothing works, i get no error, just a redirect to the same page, without being prompted. I have other bits of code that use jquery, which work fine. **the problem i have is that the confirm and method does not prompt be before continuing. What is a good way to implement jquery into an app, i have tried to include jrails, however all my other code breaks** thanks for the help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've seen this problem before, and I just found a workaround, using pure JavaScript. If you are in a hurry this might just do for now.

You can try this and you get the same effect:

```
<%= button_to("Accept Post", {}, {:onclick => "return confirm('Are you sure?')", :method => :accept_question, :remote => true}) %>
```

Comment: how can i add class and url_path ?

Comment: @Muflix <%= button_to 'Destroy', post_url(post), method: :delete, onclick: "return confirm('Are you sure?')", class: 'btn' %>

Answer (score 4):

I was just having this problem and realized that I didn't have the jquery_ujs.js file in my public directory (rails 3.0.x).

The `:confirm => "Message..."` functionality requires the unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery if you decided to scrap Prototype for jQuery. This adapter can be installed by adding `gem "jquery-rails"` to your Gemfile, running `bundle install` and then `rails generate jquery:install` (add `--ui` if you want to use jquery_ui) from terminal.
Then add `javascript_include_tag :defaults` to your application layout and you're good.

The generate command automatically fetches the jquery and jquery_ujs files for you (and jquery_ui files if you ask for them). My mistake was that I manually added the jquery and jquery_ui files, but didn't have the jquery_ujs file. So all of the jquery functionality was working, but the `:confirm => "Message..."` was not. Once I installed it, everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: +1 thanks, using rails 3.1.x now, so using asset pipeline and things are working as they should

Comment: +1 Rails 3.2 and I have a heavily customized application.js.  Just needed to add //= require jquery_ujs and the window started working.

Comment: @DevDude 's answer worked, but it seems "hacky."  I'm trying to use your way metasoarous, but to no avail.

Comment: I'll be honest - haven't been working much with rails last year or so. But perhaps folks could be more helpful if we knew what version of rails you're using?