# button_to("delete", :confirm) will not pop up and immediately executes delete method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, confirm, button-to

I've looked into this and it might be related to my javascript configs but not sure what I'm missing here:

**Views**

```
 <%= button_to("Delete Collection", @collection, :confirm => "Really delete bundle and all its examples?", :method => :delete) %>
```

**javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

**layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602520/confirm-and-method-not-working-in-rails-button-to

Comment: Yes, DevDude's answer worked, but seems "hacky."  Tried implementing metasoarous's answer to no avail.  Should I post on that thread instead?